# Why my class does not work with the error

Tags: python-3.x

class words_Deque does not work.
I am trying to make words_Deque class can transfer words into Deque class.

```
class Deque:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_front(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def add_rear(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def remove_front(self):
        if self.items:
            return self.items.pop(0)
        return None

    def remove_rear(self):
        if self.items:
            return self.items.pop()
        return None


class words_Deque:
    def __init__(self, words, deque):
        self.words = words
        self.deque = deque

    def transfer(self, deque):
        for word in self.words:
            print(word)
           deque.add_rear(word)

a = Deque()
words_Deque('mom', a)

words_Deque.transfer(a)

print(a.items)
```

expected output: ['m','o','m']
actual result: transfer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'deque'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your transfer method as it was a class method. It is, however, an instance method. Therefore, you have to call it on the instance. Try it this way:

```
a = Deque()
b = words_Deque('mom', a)   # save your instance as b

b.transfer(a)

print(a.items)
```

This produces the correct output

```
m
o
m
['m', 'o', 'm']
```